# How to process the script just once

Tags: python, events, watch, deque, inotify

My code works but I want the podman command runs uniquely when the file_queue is empty. But it start before end of data copied into /ARRIVAGE_TEST/ and runs indefinitively. The other script test_gilles_conf.py copy/past files to another directory after there are added to ARRIVAGE_TEST.

```
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path
from inotify.adapters import Inotify
import subprocess
from collections import deque
from threading import Lock, Thread

WATCH_DIR = Path('/***/ARRIVAGE_TEST')
SCRIPT_PATH = Path('/***/test_gilles_conf.py')

file_queue = deque()
queue_lock = Lock()
last_event_time = {"time": time.time()}
photoprism_process = None

def handle_event(event):
    (header, type_names, watch_path, name) = event

    if 'IN_CLOSE_WRITE' in type_names:
        filepath = Path(watch_path) / name
        with queue_lock:
            file_queue.append(str(filepath))
        return time.time()
    return None

def process_files():
    global photoprism_process
    podman_command_running = False  # Flag to track if the Podman command is already running
    while True:
        with queue_lock:
            if file_queue and time.time() - last_event_time["time"] > 5:
                if photoprism_process is None or photoprism_process.poll() is not None:
                    filepath = file_queue.popleft()
                    try:
                        env = os.environ.copy()
                        env["LAST_FILE_PATH"] = filepath
                        subprocess.run(["python3", str(SCRIPT_PATH)], env=env)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error running script: {e}")
            else:
                if not file_queue and time.time() - last_event_time["time"] > 5 and not podman_command_running:
                    podman_command_running = True  # Set the flag to indicate that the Podman command is running
                    try:
                        photoprism_process = subprocess.run(["sudo", "podman", "exec", "photoprism-app", "photoprism", "index"])
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error running Podman command: {e}")
                    finally:
                        podman_command_running = False  # Reset the flag after the command completes
                time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before checking again

def watch_directory(directory):
    i = Inotify()
    i.add_watch(str(directory))
    print("Starting file watch...")
    processing_thread = Thread(target=process_files, daemon=True)
    processing_thread.start()
    try:
        for event in i.event_gen():
            if event is not None:
                event_time = handle_event(event)
                if event_time is not None:
                    last_event_time["time"] = event_time
    finally:
        i.remove_watch(str(directory))
        processing_thread.join()  # wait for the processing thread to finish
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    watch_directory(WATCH_DIR)
```

It's a script to watch and execute another script after receive files into ARRIVAGE_TEST. I want the podman command start  after the treatment of all files but it don't work likes i expect it. Can ou help me ?

I try this :

```
else:
                if not file_queue and time.time() - last_event_time["time"] > 5 and not podman_command_running:
                    podman_command_running = True  # Set the flag to indicate that the Podman command is running
                    try:
                        photoprism_process = subprocess.run(["sudo", "podman", "exec", "photoprism-app", "photoprism", "index"])
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Error running Podman command: {e}")
                    finally:
                        podman_command_running = False  # Reset the flag after the command completes
                time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before checking again
```

but when podman command finish it always restart it.

Comment: Hi, could you please reformat your code so that the formatting renders correctly.  This will make it easier to provide help.